# How to set plain credentials for authnetication in node.js for zeromq communication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, zeromq, zeromq-js

I am using zeromq in my node.js project to communicate to a publisher socket on a python service. I have this communication successfully working but when I try to add authentication with plain username and password, it does not work.

I tried to pass the options to the constructor but that apparently is not possible. I cannot find any reference how to do that in Node.js.

Here is some of my code:

```
const s = new zmq.Subscriber({
  plain_username: 'username',
  plain_password: 'password',
});

s.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:50080');
```

When I print the subscriber I just get `Subscriber {}` empty object and I get the error that it is not extensible but how would I add authentication if it is not extensible?

Comment: What is `zmq`? Is it [zeromq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zeromq) (what version, since the docs say that 6 has breaking API changes)? Or is it [zmq](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zmq)? Or something else?

Comment: It is zeromq, the first you linked.

Comment: The one I said you needed to specify the version you were using?

Comment: 6.0.0-beta.6 is the version.

Comment: @AngelHadzhiev Have you read the docs? https://zeromq.github.io/zeromq.js/classes/Subscriber.html#plainPassword The use camelCase instead of underscores. Did you tried that?

Comment: Yes, chaing it to camelCase does remove the error of not being able to extend the object but still gives Permission denied but I am sure that the credentials are correct.

Comment: any updates on this? did you figure out how to implement PLAIN mechanism in NodeJS?

Comment: @AliOz Hey, thank you for your reply. Well, not really so we just gave up on using Node.js for that.